# Testing apps with iPhone synchronized with a pc?

Tags: iphone

My iPhone is currently synchronized with a pc. I'm planning to purchase a Mac Mini for developing iPhone apps and testing them with my iPhone. Does my iPhone have to be synchronized (via iTunes) with the Mac, in order to test my apps on it? Or can it stay synchronized with my pc?
I'm questioning this, because I want to keep my iPhone synchronized with the pc, but also want to test apps developed on the Mac.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple of choices.

You can synchronize your iPhone with multiple computers (Mac or PC), but be aware you are only allowed to sync your iPhone/iPod with up to 5 different computers (you have to authorize each computer to work with your iTunes account).

You should be able to configure iTunes on the Mac Mini to only synchronize applications and nothing else, then hopefully it won't get confused with all your other music etc (unless you want this opportunity for it to be another backup!).

Make sure you have backups, and the first time you sync it you should tell iTunes to copy everything from the iPhone onto the Mac Mini.  Otherwise later on you might find iTunes tries to delete all your apps from the iPhone to sync it with the empty iTunes account on the Mac Mini.

To avoid the hassle I just went and bought a cheap iPod Touch (you can get an 8GB one for $199 or less now) to use as a dedicated development device, but obviously it can't receive phone calls or other iPhone specific features.